# ¿Por qué al momento de realizar un respaldo a mi base de datos MYSQL desde PHP me descarga el archivo vació?

Tags: php, mysql

> este es el script php que me realiza el respaldo, pero al momento de ejecutarlo me descarga un archivo.sql dentro de un .rar pero vacío he visto muchos ejemplos iguales o muy similares que si funcionan, pero no se porque a mi no me funciona.

```
 <?php 
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'tienda';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';  
$fecha = date("Ymd-His"); //Obtenemos la fecha y hora para identificar el respaldo

// Construimos el nombre de archivo SQL Ejemplo: mibase_20170101-081120.sql
$salida_sql = $db_name.'_'.$fecha.'.sql'; 

//Comando para genera respaldo de MySQL, enviamos las variales de conexion y el destino
$dump = "mysqldump -h $db_host -u $db_user -p $db_pass $db_name > $salida_sql";
system($dump, $output); //Ejecutamos el comando para respaldo

$zip = new ZipArchive(); //Objeto de Libreria ZipArchive

//Construimos el nombre del archivo ZIP Ejemplo: mibase_20160101-081120.zip
$salida_zip = $db_name.'_'.$fecha.'.zip';

if($zip->open($salida_zip,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)===true) { //Creamos y abrimos el archivo ZIP
    $zip->addFile($salida_sql); //Agregamos el archivo SQL a ZIP
    $zip->close(); //Cerramos el ZIP
    unlink($salida_sql); //Eliminamos el archivo temporal SQL
    header ("Location: $salida_zip"); // Redireccionamos para descargar el Arcivo ZIP
    } else {
    echo 'Error'; //Enviamos el mensaje de error
}?>
```

> Tengo este otro script que si me funciona, pero solo me respalda las tablas no copia la estructura de los trigger, como puedo hacer para que al momento de hacer el respaldo respalde toda la estructura de las tabla, los procedimientos almacenado, vistas y triggers.

```
<?php
 require_once "../config/Conexion.php";
 $host = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $database_name = "tienda";
 $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database_name);
 $conn = $conexion;
 $fecha = date("d-m-Y"); //Obtenemos la fecha y hora para identificar el respaldo
 $hora = date("h:m:s");
 $tables = array();
 $sql = "SHOW TABLES";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
 $tables[] = $row[0];
}
$backupSQL = "";
foreach ($tables as $table) {
$query = "SHOW CREATE TABLE $table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$backupSQL .= "\n\n" . $row[1] . ";\n\n";

$query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$columnCount = mysqli_num_fields($result);

for ($i = 0; $i < $columnCount; $i++) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $backupSQL .= "INSERT INTO $table VALUES(";
        for ($j = 0; $j < $columnCount; $j++) {
            $row[$j] = $row[$j];

            if (isset($row[$j])) {
                $backupSQL .= '"' . $row[$j] . '"';
            } else {
                $backupSQL .= '""';
            }
            if ($j < ($columnCount - 1)) {
                $backupSQL .= ',';
            }
        }
        $backupSQL .= ");\n";
    }
}
$backupSQL .= "\n";}
 if (!empty($backupSQL)) {
 $backup_file_name = $database_name . '_backup_' . $fecha . ':' . $hora . '.sql';
 $fileHandler = fopen($backup_file_name, 'w+');
 $number_of_lines = fwrite($fileHandler, $backupSQL);
 fclose($fileHandler);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($backup_file_name));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($backup_file_name));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($backup_file_name);
exec('rm ' . $backup_file_name);
```

}

Comment: ¿Pero tu ves el archivo zip en la carpeta donde teoricamente tiene que estar? ¿y con que tamaño?

Comment: Y si en lugar de `system` pruebas con `exec($dump, $output);`. Después compruebas `if (empty($output)) { /// hay algo mal }` y comentas todo a partir de ahí (lo de comprimir el resultado)... ¿realmente hace el respaldo o no? También has de tener en cuenta la carpeta donde te lo exporta, que no la has especificado

Answer (score 0):

> Ya logre solucionar el problema

```
<?php
  $mysqlDatabaseName = 'tienda';
  $mysqlUserName = 'root';
  $mysqlPassword = '';
  $mysqlHostName = 'localhost';

  $fecha = date("Ymd-His"); //Obtenemos la fecha y hora para identificar respaldo

  // Construimos el nombre de archivo SQL Ejemplo: mibase_20170101-081120.sql
  $salida_sql = $mysqlDatabaseName . 'Respaldo'. '.sql';
  //$mysqlExportPath ='Su-nombre-de-archivo-deseado.sql';

  //Por favor, no haga ningún cambio en los siguientes puntos
  //Exportación de la base de datos y salida del status
  $command = 'mysqldump --column-statistics=0 --opt -h' . $mysqlHostName . ' -u' . $mysqlUserName . ' --password="' . $mysqlPassword . '" ' . $mysqlDatabaseName . ' > ' . $salida_sql;
 system($command, $output);


$zip = new ZipArchive(); //Objeto de Libreria ZipArchive

//Construimos el nombre del archivo ZIP Ejemplo: mibase_20160101-081120.zip
$salida_zip = $mysqlDatabaseName  . 'Respaldo'  . '.zip';

if ($zip->open($salida_zip, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true) { //Creamos y abrimos el archivo ZIP
    $zip->addFile($salida_sql); //Agregamos el archivo SQL a ZIP
    $zip->close(); //Cerramos el ZIP
    unlink($salida_sql); //Eliminamos el archivo temporal SQL
    header("Location: $salida_zip"); // Redireccionamos para descargar el Arcivo ZIP
} else {
    echo 'Error'; //Enviamos el mensaje de error
}
```